# Vaadin Push Websocket connection failed

Tags: websocket, vaadin, push, reverse-proxy

I'm using Vaadin Flow 14.10.0 with @Push annotation on main ApplicationLayout (Vaadin Spring Boot Deployment).
The application is deployed behind and Apache Reverse Proxy with the following ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse rules enabled:

ProxyPass /app/ http://172.16.120.30:8181/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://172.16.120.30:8181/

With "intranet" being the internal DNS alias of the Apache Reverse proxy, I use http://intranet/app/ to access the application and when I perform the login (http://intranet/app/login) what I can see from the browser developer console is the following error just before the home page is shown (and obviously the error remains visibile in the console):

*WebSocket connection to 'ws://intranet/app/vaadinServlet/?v-r=push&v-uiId=0&v-pushId=b2167b2b-3bf4-42e9-bb52-ab1f25dc604f&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.3.2.vaadin1-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true&X-Vaadin-LastSeenServerSyncId=1' failed:
aw @ vaadinPush-min.js?v=2.8.6:1
va*

Could anyone please help on how to remove this error condition?

Please also find attached what I can see from the browser network tab.
[image: network tab]

Many thanks,
Giuseppe.

Comment: Did you configure Apache to proxy websockets?
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Comment: It seems also weird to me that Atmosphere version is 2.3.2. Flow 2.8.6 should ship 2.7.3

Comment: @Marco C the version 2.3.2 is correct, it is the version of the Atmosphere JavaScript client, and 2.3.2 is matching with version 2.7.3 of the Java library.

Comment: @Marco C yes, the first thing we tried to do but it didn't work. With the mod_proxy_wstunnel the error is still visible in the developer console of the browser

Comment: @GiuseppeDiLuca could you provide more information? For example, all the relevant Apache configuration, errors on server log, access log, etc.
What can you see in the browser network tab related to the websocket error? Is it failing with a 404?

Comment: @Marco C just shared what I can see from the network tab, the "status" of the WebSocket row looks like "finished"

Comment: Can you share the full apache configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to share the full configuration, as it is managed from outsourcer and it contains information about other virtual hosts of our infrastructure